# What happens when aio read posix call (io_submit) is made on a file on a remote NFS server in Linux?

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

As part of my project I was asked to implement callbacks for NFS read. Now I want to understand how the current system kernel code works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At this level of detail you probably want to start by looking through existing source.. (including kernel/nfs drivers)

Comment: I tried to understand the current code. I  am not able to understand [linux code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/nfs/pagelist.c#L885) weather these requests queued are triggered parallely or are the triggered    synchronously  only after the previos repsonse is heard.